# Nginx/phpfpm not showing updated content

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, nfs, nfsclient

Server: ubuntu 14.04lts
nginx(v1.10) server is showing older content when i have already changed the file,the changes are seen after 3-6 minutes.
the document root directory is mounted from nfs share. the changes in the file is seen when i read/`cat` the file instantly but the same cant be seen on browser

Note: i have cleared the browser cache and phpopcache is disabled 
the average latency between nfs and nginx is less than 0.3ms.
No caching server/client is done

below is my nfs mount options on client side

```
mount -t nfs
10.10.17.45:/www/public_html on /www/public_html type nfs (rw,noatime,nolock,bg,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800,addr=10.10.17.45
```

below is export conf in the nfs server

```
/www/public_html 10.10.17.40(rw,fsid=0,async,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

for example:- 
I have a file called `showme.php` with below content

```
<?php $var1="abc" echo $var1; ?>
```

and if i change it to

```
<?php $var1="xyz" echo $var1; ?>
```

this is not reflected on browser

Answer (score 0):

In `<?php $var1="xyz" echo $var2; ?>`  , you ar setting `$var1` but echoing `$var2`

Answer (score 0):

This was due to nfs mount option in nfs client's /etc/fstab file

```
actimeo=1800
```

which is too long.
I reduced it to

`actimeo=1`

and its working now.